# JHipster: How to present a relationship in the same view of the owner entity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm using JHipster to create a simple application. 
The framework generates a view for each entity even though there is a relationship between the entities.
I need to present my entities in the same view.

Example: entity Question 1-->* Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster is just an app generator, you can modify the generated code as you want. About your particular question, you can do it in angular only by calling 2 entity services to display their data in same view, or you can modify one entity or its DTO to include related entity or you can create a new REST resource that aggregates the 2 entities.

By default, the fetch mode is lazy loading so if you want to load related entity have a look at [Spring data documentation about @EntityGraph](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph). Once the object is loaded you must ensure that it gets serialized in JSON with  [@JsonManagedReference Jackson annotation](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).

Comment: hello, thank you so much but how can i modify modify one entity to include the related entity?

Comment: I included some hints and links